# Airflow DAGs monitoring using Prometheus

Tags: airflow, prometheus, monitoring, directed-acyclic-graphs

Grafana version - v8.3.10
Operating system - Windows 10

We are using Prometheus to monitor Airflow DAGs.

Below are metrics provided by Airflow for monitoring,
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/metrics.html

We tried using every possible metrics but we are unable to get below points:

1. The only last run status of DAGs, if a DAG runs multiple times in a day
2. The timestamp at which it has been successful or failed
3. And no. of times it failed or no. of re-runs after failed

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: 1. Try maybe some combination of `{__name__=~"dag_processing.last_run.seconds_ago.*"}` and `bottomk(1, `?  2. `time() - <result of 1>`